# MOOC on probability

Tags: machine-learning, probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics

Hello to all my fellow users,
Please recommend me MOOC or youtube series on probability and statistics.

I had signed up in a couple of MOOCs at edx, coursera etc. However, I got confused on which course should be followed.

Comment: This is too broad as asked, because (since it is not specific about the contents or level of the course) it invites literally thousands of answers.  That just doesn't mesh with how this site works.  Please visit our [help] for more details.

Comment: I am looking for courses at beginners' level. Thank you for responding. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of courses provided by coursera, edx and other MOOC sites. You can choose one according to your need. If you want to go in some depth and higher level organisation courses you can try one of this.
http://oli.cmu.edu/learn-with-oli/see-our-free-open-courses/
https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/OLI/ProbStat/Open/about

Hope this may be helpful.